# Sort dataframe by absolute value without changing value or adding column

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that's the result of importing a csv and then performing a few operations and adding a column that's the difference between two other columns (column 10 - column 9 let's say).  I am trying to sort the dataframe by the absolute value of that difference column, without changing its value or adding another column.

I have seen this syntax over and over all over the internet, with indications that it was a success (accepted answers, comments saying "thanks, that worked", etc.).  However, I get the error you see below:

```
df.sort_values(by='Difference', ascending=False, inplace=True, key=abs)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

I'm not sure why the syntax that I see working for other people is not working for me.  I have a lot more going on with the code and other dataframes, so it's not a pandas import problem I don't think.

I have moved on and just made a new column that is the absolute value of the difference column and sorted by that, and exclude that column from my export to worksheet, but I really would like to know how to get it to work the other way.  Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Python 3

Comment: Try removing the key part.

Comment: In this version key appears: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Well I need to sort by absolute value, and I saw from other posts on internet that this was the way to do that using sort_values for a dataframe.  How do I sort by the absolute value of a column without changing its values or adding another column to sort by?  Is it possible?

Comment: I looked at that doc while trying to troubleshoot this, I don't see how anything clearly states what the issue is with my syntax.  I see the reference to the key taking a series, but I've seen the above line with key=abs posted as the solution in multiple places.  How can I sort a dataframe by the absolute value of a column without changing the values in that column and without creating a new column to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

`df.loc[(df.c - df.b).sort_values(ascending = False).index]`
Sorting by difference between "c" and "b" , without creating new column.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks P-DOX, but when I print this df both before and after the sort, I get the same order regardless of what I change the numbers to.  In addition, I don't think even if this worked that it would sort by the ABSOLUTE VALUE of the difference.  I have the difference column already, I don't need to sort without creating the DIFFERENCE column, I just need to sort the dataframe (descending) by the DIFFERENCE column's ABSOLUTE VALUE.  So, -100 should be before 90 (absolute value of -100 is 100).

Comment: df.loc[abs(df.c - df.b).sort_values(ascending = False).index]....                          
 this is what this query is doing , without creating extra column that stores the difference of df.c and df.b, we are able to sort.use abs() to calculate the absolute difference. Hope this will work.

Comment: df = df.loc[abs(df.c - df.b).sort_values(ascending = False).index]

Comment: P-DOX, this did exactly what I was looking for, although it is more robust than I needed (I have a Difference column and need to sort by absolute value of that, I don't need to figure the difference and sort without creating either. I'm pretty sure I can make this work (even though sometimes I have a hard time doing simpler than what was provided).

Recap, this sorts by the absolute value of the difference between c and b, without making EITHER a difference column OR an absolute value of the difference column:

df = df.loc[abs(df.c - df.b).sort_values(ascending = False).index]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- key is optional argument
- It accepts series as input , maybe you were working with dataframe.

[check this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: I am working with a dataframe, yes.  I am attempting to sort a dataframe by the absolute value of one column without changing that column's values or adding another column that is the absolute value and then sorting by that.  Is this not possible with dataframes?  The code line I included is the one I see as an accepted answer in other posts, but I get this key error

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the key argument. In pandas documentation we have this explanation for key argument:

*key
callable, optional
Apply the key function to the values before sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the builtin sorted() function, with the notable difference that this key function should be vectorized. It should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the input. It will be applied to each column in by independently.*

You can check this [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

To solve your problem, you can do this:

```
df.sort_values(by='Difference', ascending=False, inplace=True, key= lambda x: abs(x))
```